# How to add multi select Custom Attribute Options Programatically

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, attribute-options

I am working on to create custom attribute, While creating the attribute i need to add **multiselect** custom attribute option via code.

```
     $eavSetup->addAttribute(

            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'c_bathrooms',/* Custom Attribute Code */
            [
                'group' => 'Product Details',/* Group name in which you want to display your custom attribute */
                'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
                'attribute_set' =>  'Chennai',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Bathrooms', /* lablel of your attribute*/
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'class' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => true,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
                'filterable_in_search' => true,
                'option' => array('values' => array("1", "2","3","4","5","6"))

            ]
        );
```

i try to give option via code, that custom attrbute are created but our option only added in **admin** side and **Default Sored view**

reference:

[image: reference image]

i tried two ways:

1. 'option' => array('values' => array("1", "2","3","4","5","6"))
2. 'option' => [
                   'values' => [
                       '1',
                       '2',
                       '3',
                       '4',
                       '5',
                       '6'
                   ]
             ]

The Above two methods created custom attribute with multiselect but only added option values in **admin** side not in **Default stored view**

Suggest me How to create custom attribute with **option** that option will add **Admin** and **Default Store View** in admin side.

**Edit:**

i need to add options to both places Admin and Default Store View

Reference:

[image]

I tried Options class way that also same result

http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-how-to-create-product-custom-attribute-from-installer-in-custom-module/

Comment: Doy you want to make 1 as default ?

Comment: @Arunendra  i update my question

Comment: Did you find a solution for your case ? I am unable to programatically add attribute options specifically to multiselect attributes only.